# SQL server long datatype need to translate to int32 for EF code first application

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

In a current production database there is a mistake in the datamodel in that a child class called payment refers to a related parent class called bill through a property called billid. In the child class this is a long datatype but in the parent class it is int.

On trying to use the database and entity framework I am getting errors that bill_billid does not exist when referring to the payments as virtual properties and if I change the type to int then the code model and database model are out of sync.

Is there anyway of continuing of having the database column type remain as long due to legacy applications linked to this while converting this in my entity framework application so that my bill class can be linked to the payment class via a foreign key?

I essentially need to read the long from the SQL database and convert this to int so that my datamodel in code first will recognise the link in the tables

Comment: Have you tried adding a data annotation to your child class property? Something like `[Column(TypeName="long")]`.

Comment: How your models mapped? Using data annotations or fluent API?